# OS 10.13.3 IKEv2 VPN automatically disconnects

Tags: network, wifi, vpn

I am unable to connect through IKEv2 VPN. I fill in everything but clicking connect only tries to do that(without actually connecting) and almost immediately disconnects.

Syslog is empty, in wifi.log however I can find:

```
Sat Feb 17 19:19:54.426 <airportd[115]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
Sat Feb 17 19:19:54.620 <airportd[115]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
```

I don't really know what that means though.

This is the exact same issue as in [macOS Sierra 10.12.6 can't connect to VPN using IKEv2. How to troubleshoot?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312413/macos-sierra-10-12-6-cant-connect-to-vpn-using-ikev2-how-to-troubleshoot?newreg=7c586d08262d4f0ab7cf53bf2f876eaf)

That question remains unanswered and unfortunately due to SE policy I am unable to comment and ask if OP resolved his issue.

Is there any way I could possibly troubleshot that issue? **The VPN connection worked properly like one week ago. I haven't updated my OS since then and nothing changed in my home network.**

I tried connecting using another network and also with sharing the internet from my phone, without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was not an issue with OS X but with my IKEv2 VPN Provider - its certificate has expired.

Too bad the OS X does not state that anywhere and just instantly disconnects you, without giving any message. Even a simple text box with "There is an issue with your VPN server. Certificate has expired. " would be sufficient.

Comment: I post your answer to my provider and problem got solved. thx